# PHP - Get key value from other key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
$array = Array(
    "0" => Array (
        "id" => 1081,
        "name" => "John"
    ), 
    "1" => Array (
        "id" => 1082,
        "name" => "Matt"
    ),
    "2" => Array (
        "id" => 1083,
        "name" => "Roger"
    )
);
```

Is there anyway I can get `name` if I only know the `id` but without having to iterate through the array?

Comment: No, there isn't. Why didn't you make it an associative array in the first place?

Comment: Oh this is how I get the array unfortunately. I cannot change it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Chris 1. You could change your array structure?! 2. Question answered OR do you still need a solution for this?

Comment: @Rizier123, I cannot change the array structure. Not allowed to. But please; if you have an idea, do post it! :)

Comment: @Chris you got some advance?

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an associative array that refers to the same elements, then use that:

```
function make_assoc(&$array, $keyname) {
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($array as &$elt) {
        $new_array[$elt[$keyname]] = $elt;
    }
    return $new_array;
}

$assoc_array = make_assoc($array, 'id');
```

Now you can use `$assoc_array[1083]` to access the third item in the original array. And since this returns an array of references, modifying that will also modify the element of the original array.

Comment: 1. reading [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400234/php-get-key-value-from-other-key?noredirect=1#comment46976556_29400234) before posting is always good 2. `$new_array[$elt[$keyname] = $elt;`missing ]

Comment: I'm not changing the array structure, I'm creating a new array with different structure.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$id = 1082;
$result = array_column($array, 'name', 'id')[$id];
```

As Barmar points out, to get an array that is easy to use with `id` as the index:

```
$id = 1082;
$result = array_column($array, 'name', 'id');
echo $result[$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map`  to search into your array if your PHP < 5.5.0 and you don't have `array_column`:

```
<?php

$array = Array(
    "0" => Array (
        "id" => 1081,
        "name" => "John"
    ), 
    "1" => Array (
        "id" => 1082,
        "name" => "Matt"
    ),
    "2" => Array (
        "id" => 1083,
        "name" => "Roger"
    )
);

$find = 1082;
$value = '';

$arr = array_map(function($n) use ($find, &$value) {if ($n['id'] == $find) $value = $n['name']; }, $array);


print_r($value);

?>
```

Comment: This seems worse than a normal search loop, because it will keep going after it finds the match.

Comment: Why does OP needs > 5.5? (UPDATE: Why does he needs < 5.5 ? Can't he use it above 5.5 ?)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer PHP < 5.5 doesn't mean that OP can't use [`array_column()`](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)